# How is the performance when there are hundreds of Task.Delay

Tags: c#, .net, timer, async-await, task-parallel-library

For each call emitted to server, I create a new timer by `Task.Delay` to watch on its timeout.

Let's say there would be hundreds of concurrent calls.  Hence there would be hundreds of `Task` counting the timer.

I guess the internal implementation of TPL considered this occasion and all the tasks rely on the same underlying timer?

I am not quite understand the mechanism how the `Task.Delay` works internally.

Comment: AFAIK, all tasks use threads allocated from a ThreadPool. If you want to ensure some custom performance requirements, then you can always create a custom TaskFactory that suits your needs.

Comment: @d3dave no that's not true at all. Task.Delay uses timers not threads. TaskCompletionSource is another example of Tasks without threads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is implemented with an internal `System.Threading.Timer`. That timer class is a wrapper on top of a single native timer. To synchronize access to that single native timer there's an `AppDomain` level lock on creating new timers (and changing existing ones). You can see that in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,557):

```
internal bool Change(uint dueTime, uint period)
{
    // ...
    lock (TimerQueue.Instance)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

In most cases that's fine, but when you create a considerable amount of these timers per second you can get significant contention on that lock. The only way to actually know is to **profile your application in a real environment**.

---

I, personally, have reached that point by creating too many self-cancelling `CancellationTokenSource` using timers (you can see how I avoided that on my blog: [Surprising Contention In `System.Threading.Timer`](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/25/surprising-timer-contention/)).

There's also this post by Stephen Toub about [Coalescing `CancellationToken`s from Timeouts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/coalescing-cancellationtokens-from-timeouts/) that mentions:

> "Of course, there are always scenarios the push the boundaries of performance, and we’ve recently **seen some high-throughput cases where folks were creating one such `CancellationToken` for each of thousands upon thousands of asynchronous calls being made per second**.  That’s a lot of `Timer` and `CancellationTokenSource` instances."

Comment: I always find global locks in the BCL suprising. Another one is in ExceptionDispatchInfo. It throttles scaling of exception handling in await.

Comment: Link for your blog is invalid in your answer. [Surprising Contention In System.Threading.Timer](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/25/surprising-timer-contention/)

Comment: So this implies then that timers don't use threads?  I still don't quite follow.  My SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219573/is-task-delay-truly-asynchronous-like-an-i-o-operation-is-i-e-does-it-rely-on) was closed in favor of this, but this doesn't answer my question about threads vs hardware interrupts etc.

Comment: @rory.ap timers (and `Task.Delay`) may rely on threads, but not a thread per timer. A single dedicated thread is enough to satisfy many timers. I'm not saying that's how it works (because it's up to the OS and platform) but it shows how each wait is truly asynchronous by itself

Comment: @rory.ap and btw (regarding your question) that's how asynchronous I/O operations work. There are dedicated threads that wait on I/O completion ports but they service many truly asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 6):

If approximated delay is acceptable, an alternative is to replace `Task.Delay` with [HashedWheelTimer](https://github.com/wangjia184/HashedWheelTimer).

Code example.

```
HashedWheelTimer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
await timer.Delay(1000);
```