# Is Task.Delay truly asynchronous like an I/O operation is, i.e. does it rely on hardware and interrupts instead of a thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, delay

I've found a ton of related content that all beat around the bush and I've never been able to find an answer.  I'm almost 100% certain that `Task.Delay(int)` does not use a thread, because I can run this code on my machine with only 16 logical processors:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) tasks.Add(Task.Delay(10000));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And it takes ten seconds to complete.  If it were using roughly a hundred thousand threads it would take quite a bit longer, I'd think.

So my question is *how does `Task.Delay(int)` work?*  Not in the manner that [this poorly-entitled SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472420/how-does-task-delay-work-exactly) indicates, but from a threading and hardware resources standpoint.

Comment: You can *see the code*, here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5427 - it is based on timer callbacks

Comment: Thanks Marc I guess I'm still missing the point though...so timers don't use threads?  I guess the crux of my question would be: how is it implemented so that a timer doesn't block a thread, even with a callback?  There must be something in between the timer start and the callback.

Comment: the OS helps with things like timers

Comment: Okay, we're getting there.  So how?  The OS still needs to use threads.

Comment: The .NET timer uses one thread which does all the waiting. When you register a new timer then the timer will calculate which timer does expire next, waits for that amount of time and the fires tpl tasks to signal completion to dispatch the ready to run timer callbacks. When you register 10K timers then only one thread waits for all of them since nearby timers are collected into the same wait as far as I remember. Then 10K tasks with your expire callbacks are called via the Threadpool.

Comment: *"The OS still needs to use threads"* - for windows see [WM_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) (winapi). I have no idea how and by who windows messages are sent, you can learn more about winapi if you need.

Comment: @AloisKraus, that's just wrong, there are no threads (well, maybe very deep there are few threads servicing timer hardware, this I don't know), nothing is calculated like you explained, see [yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers).

Comment: @Sinatr: You should look at the source code linked by Marc. The .NET System.Threading.Timers are not using WM_TIMERS because that would need a Window handle and a message pumping thread. There are other ones which are but that was not the question. I did not say that there are no threads but it uses one thread to check for the next expired timers. If I count right 1 != 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current implementation of .NET, there is a single "timer thread" that just keeps track of managed timer instances and raises their events at the appropriate times. This timer thread will [block](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8cd2d3077577bf14ae568f7d2fa9de2f1556d90c/src/libraries/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/TimerThread.cs#L557) on its control signal with a timeout set to the next timer's due time. The control signal is used to add/remove/change timers, so when this blocking request times out, the timer thread knows the next timer has fired. This is a normal thread blocking operation, so internally, the thread is idled and removed from the scheduler queue until that blocking operation completes or is timed out. The timing out of those operations is handled by the OS scheduler's timer interrupt.

So technically there is a thread, but it's only one thread per process, not one thread per `Task.Delay`.

I again stress that this is in the *current implementation* of .NET. Other solutions have been proposed, such as one timer thread per CPU, or a dynamic pool of timer threads. Perhaps they were experimented with and rejected for some reason, or perhaps an alternative solution will be adopted in the future. AFAIK this is not officially documented anywhere, so this is an implementation detail.